How to Iterate over a vector of maps using clostache
I'm querying a database table and returning the following results:
[{:players/id 2, :players/name "Tony", :players/score 2, :players/created_at #inst "2024-02-13T18:56:18.608259000-00:00", :players/updated_at #inst "2024-02-14T22:29:27.838315000-00:00", :players/deleted_at nil} {:players/id 1, :players/name "Pepper", :players/score 3, :players/created_at #inst "2024-02-13T18:56:18.608259000-00:00", :players/updated_at #inst "2024-02-14T22:50:15.631414000-00:00", :players/deleted_at nil}]

I want to iterate over this vector of maps in a clostache template/view, I can get started with this:
<ul>
        {{#players}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/players}}
    </ul>

But I can't display the key values. Any idea how to display the values for each key?

In my handler:
{:players(map (fn [{id :players/id name :players/name}] {:id id :name name})
                                                     players)}

In my view/template:
<ul>
        {{#players}}
        <li>ID:{{id}} {{name}}</li>
        {{/players}}
    </ul>

